# Is it possible to use Pandas UDF to transform bags?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Is it possible to implement an aggregation operation (e.g., sum, avg, variance, etc.) on a bag (i.e., array of structs) with Pandas UDFs as an alternative to higher-order functions?

For example, using higher-order functions, I can implement average on bags as follows.

```
df = df.withColumn("average_field", expr("aggregate(bag['bag_field'], (cast( '0' as double) as sum, cast( '0' as double) as n), (acc, x) -> (acc.sum + x, acc.n + 1), acc -> acc.sum / acc.n * 1.0)"))
```

The problem with this implementation is that I have to implement average rather than being able to use a library's existing implementation. Using a pandas UDF, by contrast, is appealing because I can utilize the pandas and numpy library functions while minimizing (de)serialization overhead with Apache Arrow.

I tried Scalar Pandas UDFs but it did not work for me because I would receive a size mismatch error when passing the bag into the udf and an ArrowNotImplemented error when I pass bag['bag_field'] because it does not support StructTypes.

My latest attempt was to use GROUPED_AGG Pandas UDFs as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

def pavg(v):
    return v.mean() 

udf_avg = pandas_udf(pavg, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG, returnType=DoubleType())

my_original_fields = df.columns
df = df.groupBy(my_original_fields).agg(udf_avg(df.bag['bag_field'])).alias("average_field")
df.show()
```

This implementation gets the following error: ArrowInvalid: Could not convert [1.99 1.99 1.99 1.99 1.99] with type numpy.ndarray: tried to convert to double.

Comment: could you put a complete sample version of the data frame? It cannot be regenerated using the single liners that you provided.